# Prove that if the sequence Xn converges to X almost surely then Xn converges to X in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

[image]

I am still getting the hang of almost surely convergence, and I just learned convergence in probability. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is "almost surely" the same as convergence "almost everywhere"?

Comment: In my class we only use "almost surely" since we only deal with probabilistic spaces

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but wikipedia has this line: "Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability (by Fatou's lemma)" in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $A_m=\cap_{n \geq m} \{|X_n-X| \leq \epsilon\}$. Then $A_m$ increases to $A=\cup_n \cap_{n \geq m} \{|X_n-X| \leq \epsilon\}$. Hence $P(A_m) \to P(A)$ as $m \to \infty$. Form definition of almost sure convergence check that $P(A)=1$. Hence $P(A_m) \to 1$ which implies $P(\{|X_m-X| \leq \epsilon\}) \to 1$. [Because $A_m$ is a subset of $\{|X_m-X| \leq \epsilon\}$]. Taking complement we get $P(\{|X_n-X| >\epsilon\}) \to 0$.